# iis redirect all users except Bots

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, user-agent

How to redirect all users to http://redirect.url except "GoogleBot"

```
<rule name="nonbot" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern=".+Bot.+" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://redirect.url" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

don't work.

Comment: Is that pattern case sensitive? Because [`Googlebot`'s name and useragent string are both with a lowercase `b`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en)

Comment: Oh, really, I changed to capital letters and works now! Thank you!

Comment: In that case, I'm posting as an answer. Also, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the comments, the problem had to do with case.

Googlebot's name and useragent string both have the `b` in lowercase. The filter in the code looks for Google**B**ot. Even though the OP set the filter to ignore case, it somehow didn't. So there.